# Android and .mov files

Tags: files

How can I play .mov files on Android 2.2+ without converting them?

**EDIT:**
I am looking for a way to install Codecs rather than find a video player on the market if possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Rockplayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.redirectin.rockplayer.android.unified.lite) supports .mov files (at least the ones that I've attempted to view). The GUI isn't fantastic, it's basically just a file manager look, but I don't find myself watching video on my phone much. There could be additional options as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this forum post](http://androidforums.com/motorola-droid/20342-buddy-has-iphone-texts-me-mov-files.html#post1646872), there are a few media players on the Android Market that will play them (possibly with a little chop and jitter?) natively on the phone.